# Feed out the rope

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have question about this phrase (read in book "Gooldfinch" by Donna Tarrt):

"... a scholarship student – all sorts of special allowances and delayed deadlines and second and third chances: feeding out the rope, over a matter of months, until I’d managed to lower myself into a very deep hole."

What's mean "feeding out the rope"?.

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't find a dictionary definition for this specific sense. It's the same as [feed the steering wheel (through your hands)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22feed+the+steering+wheel%22) - it means *allow the rope/steering wheel to slip through your hands **gradually, under fine control/restraint***. But at a guess (no more than that, since I don't have OP's full context), it's likely the cited example is a highly figurative extended usage alluding to *Give a lazy student enough rope and he will hang himself*

Comment: "Feed out", in this sense, means to, in a controlled fashion, unroll from a spool or otherwise extend some material (such as rope or wire) which is long and thin.  Probably originally a nautical term, but used in a wide variety of contexts.

Answer (score 2):

This a mountaineering term:

if you **feed out the rope**, you **let go some lengths of it**, you make sure it is slack rather than taut, so that the person at the other end of the rope has freedom of movement.

Here, freedom to fall further down, to sink even deeper into whatever it was he was sinking in… and putting the blame on the people who gave him this freedom when they should have realised he was going to misuse it! The freedom of movement should allow the person to climb higher up of course, not to slip back down.

Comment: It just so happens mountaineers have reason to speak of *feeding out a rope*, but the usage isn't specific to that context. In fact, OP's metaphorical usage relates more to [spelunking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spelunking) (exploring caves), but it's no different to feeding a cable through a conduit, or any number of related usages.

Comment: *feed **out** the rope* seems to be a logical extension of *feed the rope* which appears commonly in descriptions of climbing and sailing as shown in [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feed+the+rope&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeed%20the%20rope%3B%2Cc0)